# ranges::to() error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, std-ranges, c++23

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Edge{int from, to;};

const vector<int> v1 = {1, 1} , v2 = {2,2};

vector<Edge> v3 = views::zip( v1, v2) | ranges::to<vector>();
```

compilation using g++14.

prog.cc:10:38: error: conversion from 'vector<std::tuple<int, int>,allocator<std::tuple<int, int>>>' to non-scalar type 'vector<Edge,allocator>' requested

Can this be fixed without doing (painfully verbose):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

struct Edge{int from, to;};

const vector<int> v1 = {1, 1} , v2 = {2,2};

vector<Edge> v3 = views::zip( v1, v2) | views::transform([](const auto arg){const auto [a, b]=arg; return Edge{a,b};}) | ranges::to<vector>();

}
```

Comment: you can use [zip_transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_transform_view) to make it a bit less verbose. this will remove one view and the need to deconstruct a pair: `views::zip_transform([](int a, int b){return Edge{a, b};}, v1, v2)`

Comment: it is a tiny bit better. Still depressing.

Comment: Make `Edge` implicitly constructible from `std::tuple<int, int>`?

Comment: there is not implicit conversion between `std::tuple` and your `Edge`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++23 comes zip_transform which could reduce it to this

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std; //unlearn this

int main()
{

    struct Edge
    {
        static Edge Create(int f,int t)
        {
            return Edge{f,t};
        }

        int from;
        int to;
    };

    const std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2 };
    const std::vector<int> v2 = { 3, 4 };
    
    auto edges = std::views::zip_transform(Edge::Create,v1,v2) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

    for(const auto& edge : edges)
    {
        std::cout << "edge : from " << edge.from << " to" << edge.to << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```